# Looping through an array of JSON objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I orginally was going to ask a question on why it wasn't working.  But as I commented the code I realized that I could access the text array style and `item` was giving me the index. It took me a while to find this as the solution, however I would have much rather used `item.text` in the for loop.  Is this [my posted answer] the valid way to loop through JSON objects in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - once you've parsed your JSON (which is a string) you end up with simply an object. Or an array.

Anyway, to loop through an array of objects, use a traditional `for` loop. A `for..in` loop may work, but is not recommended because it may loop through non-numeric properties (if somebody has been messing with the built-in array).

In your specific case, if `obj.body.items` is an array then do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.body.items.length; i++) {
    // obj.body.items[i] is current item
    console.log(obj.body.items[i].text);
}
```

You can also, arguably, make the code a bit neater by keeping a reference directly to the array rather than accessing it via the whole `obj.body.` chain every time:

```
var items = obj.body.items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].text);
}
```

> ***"I would have much rather used* `item.text` *in the for loop"***

In your answer - which really should've been posted as part of the question - because you are using a `for..in` loop your `item` variable is being set to each index in turn as a string, e.g., on the first iteration it will be the string `"0"`, and strings don't have a `text` property so `item.text` doesn't work - although it should give you `undefined`, not `null`. But you can do this:

```
var item;
for (var i = 0; i < obj.body.items.length; i++) {
    item = obj.body.items[i] // get current item
    console.log(item.text);  // use current item
}
```

That is, declare a variable called `item` that you set to reference the current array item at the beginning of each loop iteration.

Comment: My answer is an answer because it shows my process and the answer that I used, which does work. This is the code I am now using: `for (var item in obj.body.items) {console.log(obj.body.items[item].text);}`

Comment: I would've posted just that code in the question and said _"This works to access the properties of objects in an array, but is there a better way to do it? I'd like to be able to somehow say `item.text` in the loop."_ Your question as it now stands is kind of vague about what you're trying to do even taken with the code in your answer, and hypothetically if you were to accept somebody else's answer that would push your own answer down in the list such that other people reading the question would have to go searching to figure out what you were talking about.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I used the Q&A style thing and didn't realize it would just post my answer as an answer below, I thought it was going to do something fancier and keep them both together.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...   
    obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    // displays the object as expected
    console.log(obj);
    // display the string next as expected
    console.log(obj.body.next);
    // displays the text of the item as expected
    console.log(obj.body.items[0].text);
    for (var item in obj.body.items) {
    // displays the index value of the item
        console.log(item);
    // displays null - WHAT?? HUH?
        console.log(item.text);
    // displays the text - finally
        console.log(obj.body.items[item].text);
    }
    <script>
```

Comment: The question is `Is this the valid way to...` but you never answer your question in this answer.

Comment: Yea, this is the first time I used the Q&A style thing and didn't realize it would just post my answer as an answer below, I thought it was going to do something fancier.

Comment: Now you know it wouldn't be any fancier. :)